# How do I test my callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have three models - contact, interactions and leads.

When an interactions occurs that generates a lead (is_lead), I am updating the lead status or creating a new lead (depending if it exists or not). A lead is captured against a contact.

To achieve this, I am using a callback after_commit which calls process_interaction. See below

```
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :contact
  has_many :leads

  enum interaction_type: { file_download: 1, email: 2, telesale: 3, registration: 4 }

  after_commit :process_interaction, on: [:create, :update]

  private

  def process_interaction
    if file_download? || email? || telesale?
      lead = Lead.find_or_initialize_by(contact_id: contact_id)
      self.is_lead ? lead.active! : lead.stale!
    end
  end
end
```

The code is fairly straight forward and it works. My question is how should I go about testing this? I don't really know how to test the callback correctly. Or how to change my code so that it is more testable. I have read a lot of articles and just can't figure out how to do this. Also I am not really sure if this logic should sit in my interaction model. I am still trying to get to grips with the direction of my dependencies.

Note I did try injecting the interaction into lead by  rather doing

```
def process_interaction
    if file_download? || email? || telesale?
      Lead.process_potential_lead(interaction) 
    end
  end
```

This would achieve the same thing, but the processing would be done on the lead side. Not sure how to test this in my interaction spec and not sure which way is better.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't test the callback directly, instead I'd test the effect of the callback, which in this case is to create a Lead object and put it in the appropriate state.

So basically something like the following:

```
it 'should create an active lead' do

  ... create the appropriate interaction object ...

  lead = Lead.where(contact_id: contact_id).first
  expect(lead.active?).to be_true

end
```

Personally I'd avoid the use of callbacks and look to create a service object given you're dealing with 3 different models.  You'll most likely find it's simpler to test the service object.

Comment: From my understanding this is bad practice. You should test your models in isolation by stubbing out incoming and outgoing messages. It is pretty simple to write the above test, but it makes your test dependent on two different models.

Comment: Hence why I'd create a service object instead.  You've already coupled the models by using the Lead class inside the Interaction class.

Comment: Cool ... so I have gone off and read a bunch of things http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ and http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects I see what you are saying. Is it worth creating a service object even if it is only for a single method? Also are you saying that I need to remove my callback and move the callback call to be executed where the interaction is being instantiated? (this call would reference the new service object).

Comment: It can be worth it, the service object has more visibility in the codebase and encapsulates a piece of business logic.  Correct - you'd eliminate the callback and use the SO where the interaction is being initiated (presumably a controller).  Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand how I would test my models now. I would write a spec for my lead model and a spec for my service object. Would I write an integration test to test those two together? e.g. I have an api that logs interactions and potentially generates leads. Would I test this at a higher level to check that both of these things happen - interaction is create and lead is generated?